# LINQ syntax for left join with last added value on the right

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 tables:

```
Categories {Id, Title}
Products {Id, Category_Id, Title}
```

Ids are identity columns, there can be categories without any products.

I am using entity framework, I want to get a list of categories with the LAST added product (the largest Id of the product for that particular category).

I've been running in circles and couldn't came up with a working solution. 
Anyone can help?

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: "I want to get a list of categories with the LAST added product ", are you saying you have same id under multiple categories?

Comment: it's hard to understand what you want now, as I understand there are always last added products for each category ***unless*** some category does not have any product. If so what you want may be just all categories having at least 1 product. Another possibility is you may want all categories together with their last added product (such as put in some anonymous object `{ Category, LastAddedProduct }`).

Comment: Haven't tried this, but how about: `var results = ctx.Products.Include(p => p.Category).OrderBy(p => p.Id).GroupBy(p => p.Category_Id)`

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood you can do something like the following:

```
var res = Context.Categories
              .Select(u => new {
                  Category = u,
                  Product = u.Products.OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).FirstOrDefault()
              })
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(a => a.Category);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var categories = (from product in db.Products
                  join category in db.Categories on product.CategoryId equals category.Id
                 select category).ToList(); // Get only categories that have products

foreach(var category in categories)
{
    var lastProduct = category.Products.Last();
}
```

Comment: you are loading **ALL** products from DB into memory. that's a waste of resources.

Comment: I'm loading only categories into memory - look at the select clause. Products are used only for joining to ensure categories without any products won't be loaded.

Comment: are you sure? then where do you get `category.Products.Last()`? unless Lazy-loading is enabled...

Comment: This seems like an inefficient way to do things. You're going to get duplicated categories (if a category can contain more than one product), and the fact that you're doing `category.Products.Last` means you're loading **all** products for each category that you've loaded (lazy loading doesn't care about expression trees, it loads all related entities).